Setting onClick within template string
I am working on setting an onClick within a template string. The button is rendering as expected, but I am not getting my console log as I expect from the button click. I am basically running a server response through a parser and based off of what I getting back I am either rendering a button or an anchor tag. The button will launch a modal, while the anchor tag will just take the user to another link.
For simplicity purposes I am just setting my 2 outcomes to vars here
const testButton = `<button onClick="${()=> console.log('testing click')}">test</button>`;
const testAnchor = `<a href="${passedURL}" target="_blank">${someText}</a>`;

The anchor tag fully works as expected, but the button is not liking the onClick. I am thinking it has something to do with that.
This is on the client side within a .ts file.

How do you render your string? By default, React does not permit raw HTML.

The code within the onclick attribute of a button should not typically be a function definition, but rather code to execute. In your case, clicking the button does not call the function () => console.log('testing click'), but rather defines the function with each click, which is meaningless.
What you intend to say is probably const testButton = `<button onClick="console.log('testing click')">test</button>;.
That said, adding onclick handlers this way is not good practice. Consider creating a new button element using the dom APIs and appending a click listener to that button instead of the above.

When dealing with template strings in JavaScript (or TypeScript) and adding event listeners such as onClick, the event listener won't work directly when using the approach you mentioned. The issue arises because the onClick attribute in the HTML string is not evaluated as a function when the string is converted to HTML.
Instead, you should add the event listener programmatically after the element has been inserted into the DOM. Here's how you can achieve that:

Insert the button element into the DOM.
Select the inserted button element.
Add an event listener to the button element.

Here’s an example demonstrating this approach:


const passedURL = "https://example.com";
const someText = "Go to Example";

const testButton = `<button id="testButton">test</button>`;
const testAnchor = `<a href="${passedURL}" target="_blank">${someText}</a>`;

const container = document.getElementById('container');

if (container) {
    container.innerHTML = testButton;

    const buttonElement = document.getElementById('testButton');

    if (buttonElement) {
        buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('testing click'));
    }

    container.innerHTML += testAnchor;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template String Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



